# Did Noah's curse on Canaan affect the other Children of Ham by implication?

Tags: genesis, word-study, noah, canaan

My question deals with whether or not there is an extended prophecy about the other descendants of Ham by reason of the way Noah phrased and classified the servitude of Canaan.

It reads in Gen 9:25:

> *"A curse on the Canaanites, may they be the **lowest of servants** to the descendants of Shem and Japheth".*

**QUESTION**:

Does this imply that the other Hamites;

1) Cush=Black or Ethiopian,

2) Mizraim=Egypt, and other North    African tribes

3) Phut=Berbers, Libyans, Amazingh and other North African tribes,

Does the use of the phrase "lowest of servants" (and not "lowest servant") indicate that these other sons would be servants of a higher order than Canaan?
Or else why did Noah use the word "lowest" to describe Canaan's servitude?
 If there are servants higher than Canaan, is it sound exegetically to identify those higher order servants as Canaan's other brothers?

Answer (score 1):

This is a source of debate among commentaries (I'm Jewish, so I generally quote Jewish commentaries, which I have studied and have easy access to).

Firstly, understanding the actual translation is important.  The Hebrew term עבד עבדים is literally translated as "a servant [of] servants" or "a slave [of] slaves", and this is found in [various Bible translations](http://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Genesis%209%3A25) as well.

Kimchi and others say directly that the family of Ham will be servants to the other brothers, and Canaan will be servants of them (the rest of Ham's family). This understanding would parallel similar word usage in Deuteronomy 10:17 (Master/Lord of Masters/Lords).

Ibn Ezra and others disagree and say that if this was the case, it would have said a servant **to** the other servants, and this double emphasis implies the lowest of servants, or a very intense servitude.  This understanding would parallel similar word usage in Exodus 26:33 (Most Holy).

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1.  What baffles me is that it seems that only black Africa is being enslaved. But not all hamites were black skinned or were they. The people of tyre were Canaanites yet they were so rich and powerful even after the curse of Canaan had been fulfilled by Joshua, David and Solomon on the inhabitants of the main land.

Comment: The Egyptians according to modern scholars were not a black skinned people. Yet they were also hamites and for thousands of years they dominated the world. Until YHVH intervened in Ezekiel 29:15 to decree that "Egypt shall no longer rule over the nations for I will diminish them". So going by all this, what has happened and is happening to black Africans is baffling. They are supposed to be Cushites and not Canaanites. So that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Good points, I haven't studied and don't know the exact identification of each of Ham's offspring, so I can't comment on specific nations.  I would suggest that the curse may not always apply equally to all children at all times throughout history.  (I feel that even if just one son of Canaan was cursed, it would be a significant punishment for their family.) As you mentioned, it was fulfilled by Joshua/David/Solomon, (many commentaries point to Joshua 9 (specifically verse 23 has some similar terms), which discusses the Gibeonites who were slaves to Joshua and his men.)

Comment: Perhaps what has happened to black Africans is not related to this curse?

Comment: Ham=chamam in Arabic which means to be burnt or to be black. Ham in hebrew means hot or dusky. And Ham's first son was Cush which in hebrew means "Black",  Canaan="down low" or "subjugated", Jer 13:23 says: "can the Cushite change the color of his skin". So all these proves the ancestry of black people is from Ham. Moreover Phut/Libya, Mizraim/Egypt and Ethiopia/cush are all African nations. So Africans are Hamitic people. Just look at what our fate has been throughout history. So that's what's baffling. Maybe Noah said other things concerning the other sons which Moses ignored.  @רבותמחשבות

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Abarbanel  - Section Assessment of his works

Comment: One must not "equate" black with Canaan; to resolve this issue, one must turn to the Book of Jubilees: Ch. 10:30-34. Canaan, along with the other descendants of Noah, swore to stay in the lands given then by their father/grandfather Noah. Canaan didn't like his land-he became an insurrectionist and 'took over' the lands which are now Israel. The same spirit of insurrection haunts the Palestinians today, they were kicked out of Egypt when the tried to take over Egypt, kicked out of Tunisia, Jordan, Lebanon, and finally back in Israel again, after being kicked out.

Comment: @Tau But the Palestinians are Arabs aren't they? The pelishtiy or true philistines are lost to the archives of history. Those philistines were Hamites but Palestinians are Semites just like you are.

Comment: @user20490 Ummmmm......no. Of course, over time, no one has 'remained' 100% of their cultural heritage, so are they Arabs...? Yeah in a general cultural sense. The Important Thing is that's NOT what they call themselves....they call themselves Caananites-the "true" inheritors of the land. It started with Arafat, and now both Fatah and Hamas factions are using it. Look it up, see for yourself. That's why it's important to understand "why" God gave this land to the children of Abraham; the prior occupiers were interlopers-it was never "theirs" in the 1st place.

Comment: @user20490 In the 2008 debates, Newt Gingrich, when asked the question about the status of Israel, said the Palestinians were an "invented" people. The Media and especially the Moderator's collective jaws dropped; how could he DARE make such a statement! Of course, Newt was a history professor, not a mere ideologue. He was waiting for them to "fact check" him, which they never did-they found the truth to be 'inconvenient'.

Comment: @Tau If they are the true Canaanites, then why aren't they enslaved like the Canaanites were. I feel for the Canaanites. What happened to them was disastrous. Tau I don't fully agree with the book of Jubilees because even in the Torah, the land that Israel occupies is called by the name of Canaan. So that is Canaan's land. But because of the curse, he was dispossessed. The word Ham means "Hot". The middle East is hot just like Africa and should have been part of Hamitic territory if not for the curse. To prove it, the Arabs are the dominant group in the middle East today but even they are...

Comment: They are 2/3 Egyptian by Hagar and Ishmael's wife and they are only 1/3 Semitic through Abraham.

Comment: @user20490 They are....by their own choosing. In 1948, the Grand Mufti told them to "leave temporariy", since he had declared "holy jihad", death to all Jews, which was to be undertaken by the Pan-Arab Army. After the 'slaughter', they were to regain their homes, as well as occupy former Jewish settlements. This of course didn't happen, the Arabs were soundly defeated. The new government of Israel extended the peace branch and allowed them to return, 1/3 of Israelite's are Palestinian. But 700,000 remained in refugee camps, with no intention of returning-instead, being a bargining chip.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110170/17072) regarding the curse of Ham and the conquest of Canaanites.